# On which jQgrid event I can apply changes to jQgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to load jQgrid data(i.e sorted column, sort order, page) from cookie so that jQgrid can take changes from cookie **when  user again reopen the page** the code should take changes from cokkie are as follows:

```
function loadGridFromCookie(name) 
    {
        var c = $.cookie(name /*+ window.location.pathname*/);
        if (c == null)
            return;
        gridInfo = $.parseJSON(c);
        var grid = $("#" + name);
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortname: gridInfo.sortname });
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortorder: gridInfo.sortorder });
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { page: gridInfo.page });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
```

My entire code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getData(jqGridParams) 
    {
        var params = new Object();
        params.pageIndex = jqGridParams.page;
        params.pageSize = jqGridParams.rows;
        params.sortIndex = jqGridParams.sidx;
        params.sortDirection = jqGridParams.sord;
        params._search = jqGridParams._search;
        if (jqGridParams.filters === undefined)
            params.filters = null;
        else
            params.filters = jqGridParams.filters;

        // AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'WSAjax.asmx/GetDataForGrid',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            success: function (data, textStatus) 
            {
                if (textStatus == "success") 
                {
                    var grid = $("#ItemGrid")[0];
                    grid.addJSONData(data.d);
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    function saveGridToCookie(name, grid)     // save data into cookie
    {
        var gridInfo = new Object();
        //name += window.location.pathname;
        gridInfo.sortname = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
        gridInfo.sortorder = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortorder');
        gridInfo.page = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');
        //$('#Hidden').val(JSON.stringify(gridInfo));
        //alert($('#Hidden').val());
        $.cookie(name, JSON.stringify(gridInfo), {expires: 3});
    }

    function loadGridFromCookie(name)  // load data from cookie
    {
        var c = $.cookie(name /*+ window.location.pathname*/);
        if (c == null)
            return;
        var gridInfo = $.parseJSON(c);
        var grid = $("#" + name);
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortname: gridInfo.sortname });
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortorder: gridInfo.sortorder });
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { page: gridInfo.page });
        grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
    }

    // Jquery code
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var oItemGrid = $("#ItemGrid");
        oItemGrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 
                function (jqGridParams) {
                getData(jqGridParams);
                },
            colNames: ['Type', 'Name', 'Desc'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Type', index: 'Type', width: 40 },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 40 },
                { name: 'Desc', index: 'Desc', width: 40, sortable: false}],
            autowidth: true,
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: 'Remember Sorting and Filtering Functionality',
            pager: '#IGPager',
            loadComplete: function(data) 
            {
                var cookieval = $.cookie("ItemGrid");
                if (cookieval != null) 
                {
                    alert("From loadComplete: " + cookieval);
                    loadGridFromCookie("ItemGrid");
                }
            },
            gridComplete: function () {
                var prvData = $.cookie("ItemGrid");
                alert("stored Data from cookie : " + prvData);
                loadGridFromCookie("ItemGrid", gridInfo);
                saveGridToCookie("ItemGrid", $("#ItemGrid"));
                var storeval = $.cookie("ItemGrid");
                alert("From gridComplete: " + storeval);
            }
            //loadonce: true
        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#IGPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve these options before the initial grid declaration and set these options during the grid declaration rather than trying to do it in a during a grid event.

Based on initial information in the question I would recommend refactoring `loadGridFromCookie` to:

```
function loadGridFromCookie(name) 
{
    var c = $.cookie(name /*+ window.location.pathname*/);
    if (c == null)
        return null;
    return $.parseJSON(c);
}
```

Then use the result to initialize the grid in the document ready handler:

```
var oItemGrid = $("#ItemGrid");
var gridSettings = loadGridFromCookie("ItemGrid");
oItemGrid.jqGrid({
    sortname: gridInfo ? gridInfo.sortname : "Type",
    sortorder: gridInfo ? gridInfo.sortorder : "ASC",
    page: gridInfo ? gridInfo.page : 1,
    ...
});
```

If this is not possible jqGrid supports a `beforeRequest` event which should do the job but you may need to remove the `reloadGrid` call as this could result in the grid being loaded twice.

In addition if you want to programatically re-sort the grid it is better to use the `sortGrid` method as this will set the sort carets correctly on the column header and also call grid reload if the final parameter is set to true.

e.g.

```
grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { sortorder: gridInfo.sortorder, page: gridInfo.page })
    .jqGrid('sortGrid', gridInfo.sortname, true);
```

Comment: I can't use `beforeRequest` because my jQuery dataType is function()... what's the other option??

Comment: Can you access the cookie before defining your grid so that you can set the properties when the grid is initialized?

Comment: That's my main problem... I am not able to access my cookie... what should i do to access that cookie so that I can use saved grid's data to pass during grid initialization...

Comment: Does the $.cookie call always return null?

Comment: no.. it is returning value... but i am not getting on where I will call my loadGridFromCookie() method so that i can call this method and the method will load grid with data taken from cookie...

Comment: Can you add the code you use to create the grid to the question?

Comment: Please read my question again i have made some changes in that... sorry for making changes now...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35005/discussion-between-rahul-and-rob-willis)

Comment: Wilis : Hey thanx a lot your suggestion worked... my problem is solved...thank you so much... keep supporting...